# Returning a undefined value?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I have this code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const rf = require("select-random-file");
const token = "{DATA REVOKED}";
const prefix = "bot:"
const dir = './RandomImage'
function ranIm(){
    rf(dir, (err, file) => {
        console.log(`The random file is: ${file}.`)
        return file;
    }) 
   
}

bot.on('ready', () =>{
    bot.user.setStatus("Online");
    bot.user.setActivity('with '+bot.guilds.cache.size+" servers!");
    console.log("{BOT INITIALISED} PREFIX IS "+prefix)
})
bot.on("message", msg=>{
    let contentDown =msg.content.toLowerCase();
    let args = contentDown.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");
    if(contentDown.substring(0,prefix.length)===prefix){
        switch(args[0]){
            case 'random':
                console.log(ranIm());
                msg.channel.send("Here is your image: <3", { files:["./RandomImage/"+ranIm()]}).then(() => {
                    msg.react("✅")}, err => {console.log("Error [random]"); msg.react("❌") });          
                break;
        }
    }
})
bot.login(token);
```

But when I run the "random" command, it just logs "undefined" and the function "ranIm" has a console.log that returns a proper response like "untitled.png". How can I return the same thing as the console.log in the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `ranIm` itself does not return anything. The `return file` is inside the second argument of the `rf` function. So the return file is now the result of the `rf(dir, ...)` function.

So you need a callback parameter for the `ranIm` function like this:

```js
function ranIm(callback){
    rf(dir, (err, file) => {
        console.log(`The random file is: ${file}.`)
        callback(file)
    }) 
   
}

ranIm(function(randomFile) {
   // Do stuff with random file
})
```

Another option is using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```js
function ranIm(callback){
    return new Promise((reject, resolve) {
        rf(dir, (err, file) => {
           if (err) reject(err);
           resolve(file);
        })
    })
}
ranIm().then(file => {
   // Do stuff with random file
})
```